# How to keep both good and bad lines when loading text file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a large text file into python dataframe. One thing I noticed is, if I want to load it successfully, I have to drop all the bad lines. But I would like to load all rows first then take a look then clean it manually. Is there a way to do that?

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')
```

Here's warnings I've got. It's a common error, but all solutions are just skipping them, I really need to load all rows... any thought?

```
Skipping XXX line: Expected 28 fields in line XXX, saw 29
```

Comment: can you show the good and back lines, maybe 2 of each

Comment: If you want both lines, don't parse it as CSV in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the specific CSV file, it looks like there is either:

- Too many columns in that row (an extra comma)
- Quoting is off meaning there's a comma that *should* be quoted but isn't

The best way to remedy this is to fix the problem in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you're not just loading the file, but also parsing it at the same time.  It looks like you've handled the delimiter properly, so as you may have guessed you have too many columns or too few in some of your rows.  That may actually be the case, or perhaps you have tabs within text fields that are being interpreted as delimiters.

In any case, pandas isn't going to parse those inconsistent lines.

A typical approach is to open the file in a robust text editor and look at the lines that are erroring out in Pandas.  See what's actually wrong and either fix it in the text editor, or use python's native `open()` function to load the entire file and iterate line by line, with logic that fixes whatever the problem is.

Once you're certain that you have the same number of columns in every row load it with Pandas.